# Navigating the Bible II

Tags: tanach, trop-cantillation

Does anybody know what happened to "Navigating the Bible II"? It used to be hosted in bible.ort.org, but it's gone. I understand it featured cantor Moshe Haschel. It was a great resource. I would like to find out what was the reason to shut it down, and try to figure out a way to bring it back online.  Thanks for your help.
Pepe